# Data from Database is not being displayed

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Not too sure how to explain this but will give it my best.

I have created a database within my Android project:

public class FootySortItDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FootySortItDatabase";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public FootySortItDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        final String SQL_CREATE_PLAYER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
                PlayerDetails.PlayerTableEntry.TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                PlayerDetails.PlayerTableEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                PlayerDetails.PlayerTableEntry.COLUMN_PLAYER_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                PlayerDetails.PlayerTableEntry.COLUMN_PLAYER_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                PlayerDetails.PlayerTableEntry.COLUMN_IS_PLAYING + " INTEGER NOT NULL " +
                ");";

        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_PLAYER_TABLE);
}
```

I have set the following contract:

```
public static final class PlayerTableEntry implements BaseColumns{
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "playerTable";
    public static final String COLUMN_PLAYER_NAME = "playerName";
    public static final String COLUMN_PLAYER_NUMBER = "playerNumber";
    public static final String COLUMN_IS_PLAYING = "isPlaying";
}
```

I call a method which passes a DB and an array of details:

```
 private SQLiteDatabase playerDatabase;

    private Cursor getAllPlayers(){
        playerDatabase = ComposeMessage.addPlayerToTheDatabase(playerDatabase, playerDataSet);
        return playerDatabase.query(PlayerDetails.PlayerTableEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                null,null,null,
                null,null,null);
    }

public static SQLiteDatabase addPlayerToTheDatabase(SQLiteDatabase playerDatabase, ArrayList<PlayerDetails> listGame) {

    for (PlayerDetails i : listGame) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(PlayerDetails.PlayerTableEntry.COLUMN_PLAYER_NAME, i.name);
        cv.put(PlayerDetails.PlayerTableEntry.COLUMN_PLAYER_NUMBER, i.number);

        playerDatabase.insert(PlayerDetails.PlayerTableEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    }
    return playerDatabase;
}
```

Then, I pass the cursor into my RecyclerView :

```
public PlayerListRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, ArrayList<PlayerDetails> aPlayerList,
                                     int count) {
    playerDataSet = aPlayerList;
    this.pCursor = cursor;
    pContext = context;
```

But my pCursor = 0. Which means that their are no rows in the table??

Via the terminal I use adb to navigate to the database, use SQLite3 on the DB to search the data of the table but it does not return anything:

```
sqlite> .tables
android_metadata  playerTable
sqlite> select * from playerTable;
sqlite>
```

when I debug I can see during the insert part, that i.name and i.number has data to it and "it looks to be inserting it" but then why is cursor 0 and when I search the data, why is it not returning anything?
Not sure how to over come this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 columns in the table. None of them can be null. When you write into the database, you are writing to 2 columns instead of 3. As a result, the insertion will fail.
To create a database, I recommend [Schematic](https://github.com/SimonVT/schematic) and use [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) for debugging.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will update my code to insert into all 3 columns and then see how that goes